# Upload PDF Issue

Tags: php, laravel, upload

I am building a HelloSign API based application, for this we need to upload a PDF to HelloSign to use for a template, however the issue I am having is I also need to store a copy of the PDF on our end, I have code written but it's not working. I get the error call to member function store() on null

I have done some Googling on this and how to write this, the thing is we are already setting the template with the pdf but want to also store the file as well

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->template->setClientId(config('hellosign.client_id'));
        $this->template->addFile($request->file('pdf'));

        // here we upload the raw pdf to the database

        $path = $request->file->store('pdf');
        // create the upload and store the url
        $fileData = new Upload;
        $fileData->user_id = 1;
        $fileData->name = $request->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileData->path = $path;
        $fileData->timestamps = now();
        $fileData->save();
        /**/
```

the expected result is that when uploading it uploads the file to the server, the actual result is it gets the error "Call to a member function store() on null" on the line $path = $request->file->store('pdf');

here is a dump of the $request->file('pdf')

```
#convertedFiles: array:1 [▼
    "pdf" => UploadedFile {#468 ▼
      -test: false
      -originalName: "User Setup From.pdf"
      -mimeType: "application/pdf"
      -error: 0
      #hashName: null
      path: "/tmp"
      filename: "phpmTqOhb"
      basename: "phpmTqOhb"
      pathname: "/tmp/phpmTqOhb"
      extension: ""
      realPath: "/tmp/phpmTqOhb"
      aTime: 2019-09-25 14:34:22
      mTime: 2019-09-25 14:34:22
      cTime: 2019-09-25 14:34:22
      inode: 398565
      size: 567747
      perms: 0100600
      owner: 1000
      group: 1000
      type: "file"
      writable: true
      readable: true
      executable: false
      file: true
      dir: false
      link: false
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You probably want `$request->file('pdf')` in the couple of places you used `$request->file`.

Comment: that's how it is $path = $request->file->store('pdf'); I realized i made a typo when i posted the question

Comment: What is the name of the upload field in the HTML? is it `file`? Are you validating the input to make sure that the file exists?

Comment: @Chandler It would be helpful if you'd directly copy/paste the code. You've got the same problem at `$request->file->getClientOriginalName();` and who knows what other apparent issues are actually typos.

Comment: $request->file->getClientOriginalName(); is now $request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalName() and should work fine, the only known issue so far is with uploading the file and getting the path of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the name of the field is `pdf`.

You want

`$path = $request->pdf->store('pdf');`

Comment: awesome, that fixed it

Comment: NP. You should still add some validation to your code to make sure the file is actually there and is the right mimetype, for example. See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests